# SQL Server - Reverse Cumulative Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I have a cumulative sum that I need to reverse. How do I do this in SQL Server?

Example:

```
+---+-------------------+-----+
| id|               date|value|
+---+-------------------+-----+
| J1|2016-10-01 11:45:30|  100|
| J1|2016-10-02 11:30:30|  200|
| J1|2016-10-05 16:20:00|  400|
| J9|2016-10-06 08:35:00|  800|
| J9|2016-10-07 01:20:00|  900|
+---+-------------------+-----+
```

Desired DataFrame:

```
+---+-------------------+-----+---------+
| id|               date|value|non_cum_value|
+---+-------------------+-----+---------+
| J1|2016-10-01 11:45:30|  100|        0|
| J1|2016-10-02 11:30:30|  200|      100|
| J1|2016-10-05 16:20:00|  400|      200|
| J9|2016-10-06 08:35:00|  800|      400|
| J9|2016-10-07 01:20:00|  900|      100|
+---+-------------------+-----+---------+
```

My code:

```
select t1.id, t1.value, DIFFERENCE(t1.value) as 'cum_sum'
from @t t1
inner join @t t2 on t1.id >= t2.id
group by t1.id, t1.value
order by t1.id
```

Comment: I'm lost . . . what is the logic?

Comment: If you *are* after an *actual* cumulative sum, the logic is no different to how you would normally do it; just change the order of the `ORDER BY` from `ASC` to `DESC`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmmm . . . you seem to want to subtract the value from the "previous" row.  That would be:

```
select t.*,
       (t.value - lag(t.val) over (order by date)) as diff
from @t;
```

I'm not sure why you have "cumulative sum" in the title.  That does not help me understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is :

```
SELECT *, V - SUM(V) OVER(ORDER BY D ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
FROM   T
```

Assuming that the tested data are :

```
CREATE TABLE T (ID CHAR(2), D DATE, V FLOAT);

INSERT INTO T VALUES 
('J1', '2016-10-01 11:45:30',   100),
('J1', '2016-10-02 11:30:30',   200),
('J1', '2016-10-05 16:20:00',   400),
('J9', '2016-10-06 08:35:00',   800),
('J9', '2016-10-07 01:20:00',   900);
```